# Fetching latitude longitude datat from image on IOS in SF1 App

Tags: lightning, javascript, salesforce1-app, ios, geolocation

I need to to fetch the Latitude and Longitude of Image captured or uploaded using SF 1 App.I am  using EXIF to fetch the same in javascript(helper)
While it is working on android , same does not work on IOS. Anyone have any idea how to do it.
Below is part of my code which I tried:

```
 pic.onload = function(){
                                    alert('EXIF'+EXIF);

                                    window.setTimeout(
                                        $A.getCallback(function() {
                                            EXIF.getData(this, function (){
                                                alert('inside exif');
                                                alert('lat'+EXIF.getTag(this, 'GPSLatitude'));
                                                alert('long'+EXIF.getTag(this, 'GPSLongitude'));
                                                var longitude = EXIF.getTag(this, 'GPSLongitude');
                                                var latitude = EXIF.getTag(this, 'GPSLatitude');
                                                if((longitude != null && latitude != null && typeof latitude != 'undefined' && typeof longitude !='undefined') || component.get("v.isLatLongRequired")  == false)  {
                                                    if(longitude != null && latitude != null && typeof latitude != 'undefined' && typeof longitude !='undefined'){
                                                        console.log('image contains lat long'+(latitude[0].numerator + latitude[1].numerator /(60 * latitude[1].denominator) + latitude[2].numerator / (3600 * latitude[2].denominator)));
                                                        component.set("v.latitude", (latitude[0].numerator + latitude[1].numerator /(60 * latitude[1].denominator) + latitude[2].numerator / (3600 * latitude[2].denominator)));
                                                        component.set("v.longitude", (longitude[0].numerator + longitude[1].numerator /(60 * longitude[1].denominator) + longitude[2].numerator / (3600 * longitude[2].denominator)));
                                                        console.log("latitute"+component.get("v.latitude"));
                                                        console.log("longitude"+component.get("v.longitude"));
                                                        if(component.get("v.latitude") == null || component.get("v.longitude") == null || isNaN(component.get("v.latitude")) || isNaN(component.get("v.longitude")))
                                                        {
```

Answer (score 1):

it doesn’t work on iOS because the OS clean up the geolocation during the upload. Your code should work on iOS for an image uploaded on Android. That will confirm it.

Comment: Hi @Jean, Yes I got it, but do I have any work around here, as this is required thing in my  project, as I need to have the location values of image uploaded via IOS. I am stuck on the same after trying a lot.